# How to protect against http/0.9 evasion request? [flask]

Tags: python, http, flask, bad-request, http-0.9

I've been getting some weird http requests on my AWS server. I run a python3/flask v0.12 web server on it.

Does anyone know if I should be worried about the requests below?

Is there anyway to automatically reject old http requests (e.g. http/0.8 or http/0.9) using flask?

```
77.72.83.21 - - [18/Mar/2018 22:46:32] "╚  *%à     Cookie: mstshash=Test" HTTPStatus.BAD_REQUEST -
77.72.83.21 - - [18/Mar/2018 22:46:34] code 400, message Bad HTTP/0.9 request type ('\x03\x00\x00*%à\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00Cookie:')
77.72.83.21 - - [18/Mar/2018 22:46:34] "╚  *%à     Cookie: mstshash=Test" HTTPStatus.BAD_REQUEST -

213.202.230.144 - - [19/Mar/2018 11:11:00] code 400, message Bad HTTP/0.9 request type ('\x03\x00\x00/*à\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00Cookie:')
213.202.230.144 - - [19/Mar/2018 11:11:00] "╚  /*à     Cookie: mstshash=Administr" HTTPStatus.BAD_REQUEST -
```

Comment: Got the same question :)

Comment: Hi , did you find any help about this?

Comment: When I try remote RDP to my server `server_ip:server_port` on Ubuntu with `Remmina`, login fail with username `Administrator` and none password. I got same result.